# Tracking the point until when the code ran

Tags: java

I need to track the point until when the code ran. Consider the program given below:

```
function f() throws Exception{
    statement 1 //can throw exception
    statement 2 //can throw exception
    statement 3 //can throw exception
}
```

I need a mechanism to identify at what point the exception occurred, one way is to do this using exceptions, i.e. creating a variable in exception itself, or pass something by reference to function f and use it to identify at what point did the function the ran successfully.

Which is the better way, or is there any more elegant way to do this?

Comment: do you throw these exceptions or API that you are using?

Comment: I throw at catch the exception at some upper level, at that level I need to figure out a way if the code ran at some point, so that I can take specific actions.

Comment: Do you have the hand on `f`? Can you change it? If so, some "try catch" around each statement can help you wrap exception thrown in a custom one and handle the custom one later. Some aspect is probably another solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common mistake is to not print out the stack trace, or not print out the exception at all.  Don't do that in most cases, because you are throwing away useful information.

I would use the debugger to step through the code or find the exact point an exception is thrown, or you could read the stack trace for the exception.

```
public static void f() throws Exception {
    statement1(); //can throw exception line 101
    statement2(); //can throw exception line 102
    statement3(); //can throw exception line 103
}
```

When the stack trace says it threw an exception on line 101, 102 or 103, this tells you which statement it was executing.

If you need to do this at runtime, doing something different each time I would put each one in a try/catch block.

```
public static void f() throws Exception {
    try {
        statement1();
    } catch (TheException e) {
        doSomething1();
        // return or throw
    }
    try {
        statement2();
    } catch (TheException e) {
        doSomething2();
        // return or throw
    }
    try {
        statement3();
    } catch (TheException e) {
        doSomething3();
        // return or throw
    }
}
```

Comment: I need it at runtime, I guess the solution wont work.

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja reading the stack trace can be done at runtime as well, however you need to know what the line numbers mean. A better approach is to use a different exception whenever you expect different behaviour, or place each statement in it's own try/catch block.

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja I have added an example of using multiple try/catch blocks.

Comment: using line numbers at runtime is pretty risky I guess, making custom exceptions is a viable option though.

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja they could be different to imply a different actions should be taken.  You should look at what built in exceptions there are and use these or have custom exceptions sub-class the most appropriate exception.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to do a little trick, but I'm not sure whether it is correct.

```
public class ExceptionLevel extends Throwable {
    private int value;

    public ExceptionLevel (int v) { value = v; }
}
```

Then, when you throw an exception (it need to have a `Throwable(Throwable cause)` constructor), you should

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.initCause(new ExceptionLevel(1)); // from the first statement
    throw new AnyException("message", e);
}
```

To handle all of this (inside of a global `catch` block)

```
int statement = e.getCause() == null ? 0 : ((ExceptionLevel)e.getCause()).getValue();
```

I think you understand my main idea. You may improve it a little bit by making `ExceptionLevel` as last cause in your [chain of exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/chained.html).

Comment: This is probably a solution but the original exception gets lost, and that's bad

Comment: I would use a different exception for different behaviour or use a text `message` if I didn't want lots of Exception classes.

Comment: @RC., we can build a chain of causes, there is nothing to loose